# LiveData (backed by Flow) in Test is reflecting old value

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-testing, kotlin-flow

I am trying to write a test for my View Model that verifies when I call `setFirstTime`, the `state` of the view model contains the updated value for `firstTime` set to `false`.

The `UserPreferencesRepository` provides a `Flow` of the preferences to the viewmodel, which exposes them as `LiveData` (using `asLiveData` extension).

Here is my test I am having trouble with:

### MainViewModelTest.kt

```
package com.example.fitness.main

import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import com.example.fitness.MainCoroutineRule
import com.example.fitness.data.UserPreferencesRepository
import com.example.fitness.getOrAwaitValue
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidRule
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is`
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository

    @Before
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()

        // Execute all pending coroutine actions in MainViewModel initialization
        mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
            mainViewModel = MainViewModel(userPreferencesRepository)
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun `#setFirstTime marks the user as have opened the app at least once`() {
        assertThat(mainViewModel.state.getOrAwaitValue().firstTime, `is`(true))

        mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
            mainViewModel.setFirstTime()
        }

        # Failing assertion. Comes back as `true` when I expect it to be `false`
        assertThat(mainViewModel.state.getOrAwaitValue().firstTime, `is`(false))
    }
}
```

### MainViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.fitness.main

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.fitness.data.UserPreferencesRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userPreferencesRepository: UserPreferencesRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val state = userPreferencesRepository.userPreferencesFlow.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Persists a value signifying that the user has started the app before.
     */
    fun setFirstTime() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userPreferencesRepository.updateFirstTime(false)
        }
    }
}
```

### UserPreferencesRepository

```
package com.example.fitness.data

import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.booleanPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import javax.inject.Inject

data class UserPreferences(
    val firstTime: Boolean
)

class UserPreferencesRepository @Inject constructor(private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>) {
    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val FIRST_TIME = booleanPreferencesKey("first_time")
    }

    val userPreferencesFlow: Flow<UserPreferences> = dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
        val firstTime = preferences[PreferencesKeys.FIRST_TIME] ?: true
        UserPreferences(firstTime)
    }

    suspend fun updateFirstTime(firstTime: Boolean) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.FIRST_TIME] = firstTime
        }
    }
}
```

I verified via the debugger that the body of the `dataStore.edit` code is being run prior to the last assertion of the test. I also noticed that the body of `dataStore.data.map` is also being run after the update, with the correctly populated `preferences` set to false. It appears that running the test in debug mode and quickly stepping through my break points results in a passing test, but running the test normally produces a failure, which leads me to believe there is some race condition present.

I am basing my work off of a [Google Codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-datastore/tree/preferences_datastore). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to determine what the issue was. When I am creating my `DataStore` in the app, I am using the default coroutine scope, which is `Dispatchers.IO`. In my tests, I was replacing the main coroutine with `kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher`, but I needed to somehow instantiate the `DataStore` with a `TestCoroutineScope` as well, so that those saving actions would run synchronously.

Taking a lot of liberties from this [extremely helpful article](https://www.wwt.com/article/testing-android-datastore), my final code looks like:

### MainViewModelTest.kt

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainViewModelTest : DataStoreTest() {

    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() = runBlockingTest {
        val userPreferencesRepository = UserPreferencesRepository(dataStore)
        mainViewModel = MainViewModel(userPreferencesRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun `#setFirstTime marks the user as having opened the app at least once`() = runBlockingTest {
        assertThat(mainViewModel.state.getOrAwaitValue().firstTime, `is`(true))

        mainViewModel.setFirstTime()

        assertThat(mainViewModel.state.getOrAwaitValue().firstTime, `is`(false))
    }
}
```

### DataStoreTest.kt

```
abstract class DataStoreTest : CoroutineTest() {

    private lateinit var preferencesScope: CoroutineScope
    protected lateinit var dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>

    @Before
    fun createDatastore() {
        preferencesScope = CoroutineScope(testDispatcher + Job())

        dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(scope = preferencesScope) {
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.preferencesDataStoreFile(
                "test-preferences-file"
            )
        }
    }

    @After
    fun removeDatastore() {
        File(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().filesDir,
            "datastore"
        ).deleteRecursively()

        preferencesScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

### CoroutineTest.kt

```
abstract class CoroutineTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    protected val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testDispatcher)

    @Before
    fun setupViewModelScope() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun cleanupViewModelScope() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @After
    fun cleanupCoroutines() {
        testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        testDispatcher.resumeDispatcher()
    }

    fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend TestCoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
        testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest(block)
}
```